# IIS Does not refresh changes on web references ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, iis, virtual-machine

I am working over a Virtual Machine using Microsoft Azure, and I installed an app into the IIS, however the when I want to replace the files I've transferred via FTP (From my Local computer to a VM folder) the IIS does not refresh the changes. These are the steps I've run:

1. Site -- Add new website
2. Fill up all the required fields
3. Start the app

but what I can see in the browser is old application, I tried to modified the code but the changes never displayed in the screen.

Note: it is a web service which I try to modified. 
Note: I've tried, iisreset, stop the web site, re-start it, re-start the server, deleting the web site, re-create the web site but nothing works.

I am using 4.5.0 in my web app, in [Web.config]. 
Windows Server 2016.
IIS 10.

Is there something which I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Clear your browser cache and try again.

Comment: I've already done that, didn't work. :(

Comment: right now the question cannot be answered at all. Double check all steps. I doubt if you are manipulating a wrong machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that there is something in VS2015 solution which does not allow to refresh the web service once the new files are updated via FTP. What I did was to install the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-7-5-computer and configure the Visual Studio to Deploy the web service to IIS in the Virtual Machine. This was the link which helped a lot. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis

**RECOMMENDATION**

DO NOT deploy a web site or service using FTP, it is better to set the ports in the VM and run the deployment from VS properly.

Answer (score 0):

Check to be absolutely sure that you are overwriting the original files. I have seen some ftp clients show a very small status window that can make it easy to assume the files are transferring due to the flood of messages streaming by when in reality there are permissions issues preventing you from overwriting files. Expand the logging window for whatever client you're using so that you can confirm for certain that your files are actually transmitting.  If they are, maybe you're dropping them in the wrong folder.